# ModuleNotFoundError when importing the arisma model

Tags: python

Hi I'm getting the following error while trying to work with the ARISMA model in python. Can someone help me to understand what I'm missing

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arisma_model import ARISMA
```

error getting is,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-099aced65df8> in <module>()
     28 import seaborn as sns
     29 from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
---> 30 from statsmodels.tsa.arisma_model import ARISMA

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.tsa.arisma_model'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to say arima_model instead of arisma_model?